# Is it impossible to resize the webcam in React?

Tags: reactjs

The webcam shows properly. But The size could not be adjusted as desired.
Is it impossible to resize the webcam in React?

`<Webcam className="user-webcam"></Webcam>`

```
.user-webcam{
    width: 540px;
    height: 840px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 70px 0px 0px 70px;
}
```

Comment: Which Library Are You Using For Web Cam

Answer (score 0):

This is because the video maintains the default aspect ratio.

You can add `object-fit: cover;` property to `.user-webcam` class.

Comment: @김지수 I'm glad that I could help. So, could you please accept this answer and thus close the question? – Bart Krakowski 23 mins ago   Delete